# Assigning a QDateTime to QDateTimeEdit within QTableWidget

Tags: javascript, qt, squish

I'm working on a function in which I hope will set the correct date/time of a QDateTimeEdit object within a given table cell. The function is as follows:

```
function setCalDateTime(iRow, month, day, year, hour, minute, ampm) {
// We get a handle to the cell containing the widDateTimeSelect
var cellOfInterest = waitForObject("{name='tbl_SourceInventory' type='QTableWidget' visible='1'}").cellWidget(iRow,3);
// We break apart the contents of the cell into its individual elements
var cellContents = object.children(cellOfInterest);
var tblModel = findObject("{type='QTableModel' unnamed='1'}");
// We search the contents of the cell for the QDateTimeEdit widget of interest.
for (var i = 0; i < cellContents.length; ++i) {
    if(typeName(cellContents[i]) == "QDateTimeEdit") {
        var dtString =  month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
        var dateTimeObj = QDateTime.fromString(dtString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AP");
        if(dateTimeObj.isNull() || !dateTimeObj.isValid()){
            test.fail("setDateTimeInDateTimeControl: Failed to create a valid datetime object");
        }else{
            cellContents[i].setDateTime(dateTimeObj);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

If this looks a bit odd its because we are using Froglogic's Squish for QT toolkit. We write test cases using JavaScript but are able to gain access to QT objects and thus call public functions and slots on these objects.

If I were to create a test case in which I were to get a handle to a QDateTimeEdit object that was *not* contained within a table the logic of setting the new QDateTime object above works. 
If I were to debug the above code the function as presented works.

If I were to just run the test this function fails on `cellContents[i].setDateTime(dateTimeObj);` If I look at the debug file, the thing that stands out most is the following: Access violation - code c0000005.

Two questions of interest:
1. How best should I be setting a QDateTimeEdit object that is contained within a table cell.
2. Why does it allow me to set the correct date time when I'm stepping through the code?

I certainly appreciate any guidance that might point me in a direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 2 first:

The main difference of going through the operations step by step is speed. Particularly, GUI applications constantly process events in the background. When giving the operations more time you may enable some important events to be processed. Like a full loading of your table. When accessing the cells in an intermediate phase you may be accessing an object that got deleted behind the test script's back.

The answer to question 1 may be related: your script is probably fine. But it may suffer from a race condition. I suggest to try whether adding a wait statement like `snooze(3)` makes the problem go away. That's note a permanent solution but if it helps other synchronization methods (e.g. `waitFor()`) can be employed.